# Which type of widget is this used in an Android app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-widget

It is an Android app I have to know which type of widget is used in this picture.

When I click on that is expanding

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Expandable list** view, like below.

Please check this

[click here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView)

Answer (score 0):

It can be expandable list or it can be expandable recyclerview but if you want to do the same i will suggest you to go with expandable recyclerview it will be more easy to and performance will much faster then list view.